# EXTRA xtreme Attachmate Pagedown function

Tags: ibm-midrange, attachmate-extra

I am using a Windows Form Application to open a EDP file and navigate AS400 system. Can someone specify the right format to give `page_down`.

```
MyScreen.SendKeys("<PG_DN>");
MyScreen.SendKeys("<PAGE_DOWN>");
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the proper key command looks to be here: https://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/5250functionkeys_des.htm

My guess is that you are looking for "RollUp" and "RollDown".